# What would be a viable and justifiable policy to handle short-term acute pollution incidents across large urban areas such as Delhi?

Tags: air-pollution

Air pollution in Delhi has rose up to hazardous level with air quality index crossing 500 in many areas. But unlike other polluted cities (like Beijing), Delhi has no shut down of schools and businesses. Such a shut down would not only prevent people from its hazardous effects but also reduce pollution levels due to closed industries and less vehicular traffic. So why does this not happen? What are other possible solutions to protect people from this hazardous situation.

Comment: My understanding is that while Beijing has some severe pollution events these tend to be fairly short (not that the norm is exactly clean). In Delhi the highest levels of pollution can be sustained for long periods.

Comment: A novel approach is outlined [here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-india-38285567). Basically it proposes using jet engines to propel the pollution high into the atmosphere - although of course it would be better to reduce the emissions at source.

Answer (score 3):

Delhi has acute pollution issues once a year during the time farmers around Delhi burn the waste after the crop has been harvested, this combined with adverse wind directions or weather conditions makes the problem worse. The major part of the problem come from outside Delhi rather than within Delhi, banning stubble burning would and should IMO to a large extent help in reducing the pollution. Agreed that Delhi's AQI isn't great even without all the stubble burning but those problems require long term policy decisions such as moving towards BS-VI fuel, CNG powered public transport, electric vehicles and regulating polluting industries.

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! Good answer. Stopping crop stubble burning will improve air quality and prevent loss of soil nutrients, but what about farmers who have no choice but to burn stubbles because they cannot afford machinery to clear their fields?

Comment: The waste can be dumped in a common location in each village after which it can be cleared by the govt. on a regular basis during the harvest season or be used as feed for bio-gas plants.

Comment: It's a good idea, but I think there is still the problem that some farmers do not have the time or money to remove the stubbles and/or transport it. See for example [this article](https://indianexpress.com/article/india/india-news-india/stubble-farm-fire-slash-burn-agriculturepunjab-haryana-pollution-health-hazards-3074434/)

Answer (score -1):

Because is no system in place to do so. There is no regulation. There are no Public health warnings.

Arbitrarily, schools might be shut down either by their own choice or by government under public pressure.

Sadly, this is the state of most Indian cities. On the other hand, if there is a parents association and it declares that they wont vote for the current government in next election, only then would some action will be taken.

Comment: After edits to the question this answer no longer applies.

Answer (score -3):

One way is to replace polluted by air by clean air..Hence growing plants and saplings and nurturing them into trees. We have to start at our own place, before saying where is the space to grow it..Thanks.

Comment: *growing plants and saplings and nurturing them into trees* is not an answer to *short-term acute pollution incidents*